# Check if a dataframe column contains a particular value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use an if-else statement to check if a dataframe column 'vi' contains a value, then extract the value in the next corresponding row. The dataframe contains 2 columns, 'j' and 'vi'

```
if G_df['vi']== vi:
    new_j = G_df.loc['j'].item()
```

gives the is error:
    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I also tried:

```
if G_df['vi'].item() == vi:
    new_j = G_df.loc['j'].item()
```

and got this error:
    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1):

The value of `G_df['vi']== vi` is a Series. You cannot use it in an `if` statement. Also, `if` statements should be avoided in Pandas. Here's what you are looking for:

```
df.loc[df['vi'] == vi, 'j']
```

This expression gives you all values from the column `'j'` where the column `'vi'` is equal to `vi`.

Comment: Ok. I didnt know i couldnt use it in an if statement. thanks. I did new_j= G_df.loc[G_df['vi'] == vi, 'j'].item(). but when i try to use the value of new_j to indicate the coulumn of a matrix im building, it says ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
but new_j is an int. what am i doing wrong